# How to access a Matlab field inside a struct from C#

Tags: c#, matlab

**Assume the following in Matlab:**

```
%variable info contains a <1x2 struct>, so...
info(1,1);
info(1,2);

%these contains fields like .a .b etc.
info(1,1).a = [1, 2, 3, 4, etc... ];
info(1,2).b = [1, 2, 3, 4, etc... ];
```

**Now in C#:**

Normally, I would do something like:

```
//assume I received the variable info from an output parameter
//of a MatLab function, called via InterOp
MWNumericArray fieldA = (MWNumericArray) info.GetField("a");

//Remember that info contains 1row with 2 columns
```

I want to access the fields from both columns

```
//this is what i've tried, and failed, with  the exception for data["a",1]
MWNumericArray fieldA = (MWNumericArray) data["a", 0];
MWNumericArray fieldA = (MWNumericArray) data["a", 1, 1];
MWNumericArray fieldA = (MWNumericArray) data[0];
```

***So how do I access a field from inside a nameless struct ?***

While step debugging, VisualStudio defines `info` as a

```
info = { 1x2 struct array with fields: a b }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, are you satisfied with the answer you found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solved by using:**

```
MWNumericArray fieldA = (MWNumericArray) data["a", 1]; //data(1,1).a
MWNumericArray fieldB = (MWNumericArray) data["b", 1]; //data(1,1).b
fieldA = (MWNumericArray) data["a", 2]; //data(1,2).a
fieldB = (MWNumericArray) data["b", 2]; //data(1,2).b
```

**Remember mathematicians count from 1, programmers from 0.**

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help :

```
MWNumericArray fieldA = (MWNumericArray) info.GetField("a"); //defines info as a
MWNumericArray fieldB = (MWNumericArray) info.GetField("b"); //defines info as b

MWArray resultA = fieldA[0];
MWArray resultB = fieldB[0];
```

show data:

```
System.out.println(fieldA);
System.out.println(fieldB);
```